# How can I set black color to my label background color when dark mode is off?

Tags: swift, ios13

I want the background color of the label to be black when dark mode is OFF and the background color of the label to be white when dark mode is ON (iOS 13).

Which UIColor value gives me black in light mode and white in dark mode?

When the user turns on dark mode, all blacks should change to white. `UIColor.black` doesn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't that be your own or product requirement? How can we tell what colour you should or want to use?

Comment: I want when the user on his cellphone turns on dark mode . All blacks change to white . UIColor.Black dosn't work @PGDev

Comment: You say "the label". What label?

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 13, `UIColor.label` is black in light mode and white in dark mode.

```
someLabel.backgroundColor = .label
```

Of course you now need an appropriate `textColor` for the label so you can read the text. Using `UIColor.systemBackground` will give you white in light mode and black in dark mode.

```
someLabel.textcolor = .systemBackground
```

Comment: "did not work" is not a useful description of your problem. The code I posted will give you white text on a black background in light mode and black text on a white background in dark mode. That is what you said you wanted. And that's what it does.

Comment: my friend At first run the colors are right. But when I turn the dark mode on and off, the colors don't change

Comment: i used .label and i have this issue

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. But you have not provided any useful details in your question so no one can help you.

Answer (score 0):

um, for black, use `UIColor.black` and for white, `UIColor.white`?

It sounds like you're asking how to make your app respond to the user selecting/deselecting dark mode. I suggest reading the Apple document on the subject:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/

Comment: I want when the user on his cellphone turns on dark mode . All blacks change to white . UIColor.Black dosn't work